# Squid user password failed to authenticate after upgraded to CentOS 6.4

Tags: squid, centos6

I setup a squid proxy server on [CentOS](http://centos.org) 6.3, all works fine. Recently I upgraded CentOS to 6.4, now all the squid user password can not pass the authentication.

I use basic [ncsa_auth](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/auth_param/) scheme, and the password file works fine on CentOS 6.3, [Fedora](http://fedoraproject.org) 18 and [squid for windows](http://squid.acmeconsulting.it/).

Is it a bug or something else?

**Test result**

```
[root@proxy ~]# /usr/lib64/squid/ncsa_auth /etc/squid/squid-htpassword-cm.txt
glsx glsx
ERR Wrong password
^C

[root@proxy ~]# cat /etc/squid/squid-htpassword-cm.txt
glsx:$apr1$VMNrr3BE$ljryzy0FyTLY3OU2Yhd/f/
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `ncsa_auth` in CentOS 6.4 no longer accepts the md5 form of passwords anymore but I don't know why. If you test DES one it will work.

Comment: I don't see `DES` in htpasswd options, is `-d (CRYPT)` option using DES? `htpasswd -nbd USER_NAME PASSWORD`, right?

Comment: It seems `SHA` encryption don't work too

Comment: @LiuYan刘研 Yes, crypt is based on DES (salt was added). _Or just -nb as -d (crypt) is default one._